# How to replace anchor links in angular v6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, router, angular-router

I am building an angular app I have an anchor link

```
<a routerLink="." fragment="home" >Home</a>
```

so by clicking this link the browser will scrolldown to the home section  and the url will be **myapp.com#home** 
my question is how can i change the url and have **myapp.com/home** without creating a router, because of the html template that im using which is a multipurpose template (ex: [template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB080K57G))

Comment: Just `href="/home"`? Not sure what you mean by "without creating a router" though, and what the actual point is.

Comment: So `/home` is a route and you can't make this work without a route registered to the router.

Comment: You totally right but my problem is based on the template that i have theres no concept of pages to navigate Its only a single page With a couple sections stack on top of each other so when the user click on the achor link #about so the browser will scrolldown to the target section which About so based on this template how am i gonna define a route... this is an example of the template that i have http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB080K57G